# Probability of a point lying in a space

Tags: probability

Actually I really don't know that if any book had printed this question ever or not but this is just a random question that came into my mind when I was studying 3-D Geometry and suddenly thought of probability. So here it goes.

> **Question**: What is the probability of selecting a random point in a space such that it'll lie in a given plane (for instance like *x-y* plane) provided that point have integral co-ordinates?

I am really sorry if it had gone beyond the stupidity but this is it. However being a random question I still attempted it and here is what I tried.

> **Attempt**: So selecting a random plane like for sake of simplicity. From this I further assumed whole space to be an infinitely big cube having origin at it's center and took it's dimension to be $\mathrm{2n*2n*2n}$ (means all it's faces are $\mathrm{n}$ units far from center).
>
> [image]
>   *Figure*: An $\mathrm{n}$ sided cube with origin at the center
>
> Furthur if I cut the given cube from the center in two equal parts (for visualising the *x-y* plane), I would be getting a square of dimension $\mathrm{2n*2n}$ having $\mathrm{(2n+1)*(2n+1)}$ co-ordinates. 
>   Further there would be $\mathrm{(2n+1)*(2n+1)*(2n+1)}$ co-ordinate points.So taking the probability of the points we will be having
>
> $$\mathrm{P=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n+1)^2}{(2n+1)^3}}$$
>   $$\implies \mathrm{P=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2n+1}}$$
>   $$\implies \mathrm{P=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1+2n-2n}{2n+1}}$$
>   $$\implies \mathrm{P=\lim_{n\to\infty}1-\frac{2n}{2n+1}}$$
>
> And by L'Hopital Rule differentiating the denominator and numerator of the limit I have
>
> $$\implies \mathrm{P=0}$$

So this was my approach. But I think there is some major flaw in this since I am getting zero.

**Note:** Ignore the relativity error.

Can anyone give any comment on this?

Comment: This needs some work: What is the process of selecting points? Can you only select points on the integer lattice? Is the plane defined ahead of time or is also randomly generated? If so, how?

Comment: There is no such thing is "picking a point at random". You must specify the probability distribution, otherwise you did not pose a question.

Comment: @IttayWeiss "provided that point have integral coordinates"

Comment: @Eupraxis1981 Yes. "The points have integral co-ordinate". And please don't consider any relativity errors.

Comment: @DheerajKumar how does that matter? There is no such thing as randomly choosing anything, except from a sample space with one point. You must specify the probability distribution, and as soon as there are more than one point, there are infinitely many such probability distributions.

Comment: @IttayWeiss There are fixed number of integral points inside a cube say $n$ , Don't you know how to choose a point out of $n$ of them.

Comment: please read my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

1. Fix a plane.
2. The set of all integer points lying on the plane depends on your choice. Extreme examples being:

   - The $z=0$ plane has (countably) infinite number of integer-points that lie on it.
   - The $z=1/2$ plane has none.
3. That being said, the probability you are looking to calculate will always be the same - infact it will be zero. This is because even in the extreme case, (like that of $z=0$) there will only be countably many integer points on the plane. As a result, their (probability) measure will be zero.

Conclusion: $P=0$ is the correct answer, though you have to define a probability measure on your space for making your question rigorous.

Comment: and once a probability measure is chosen the correct answer can be anything between $0$ and $1$, so no, the correct answer is not (necessarily) $0$.